# how to translate chinese characters in an image to english?

Tags: image, ocr, barcode-scanner

I recently bought a Barcode scanner online and when i got it, I noticed that the entire user guide is in chinese (Simplified)... I was wondering if there was some sort of OCR software out there that could take a scanned copy (.jpg) and turn it into an English-translated copy (.txt or .doc) ? I have tried JOCR.exe and that works perfectly with every language except chinese, japanese, and other foreign languages. to use those languages i need to aquire the language packs for MS Office's OCR Plugin. If OCR is not the best method in this situation, then what would be? Any and all Advice would be appreciated!